# Trade off for CSS sprites: how many images to combine into one

Tags: css, optimization, css-sprites

I wonder what the best trade-off for combining images for CSS sprites is.

Say I have 50 images, but each page only needs 5. The total size of a sprite image is 100kb.

There obviously are a dozen of parameters, how many pages are visited in each visit, the connection speeds of the users, the lag. I'm not looking for a mathematical formula to compute the best trade-off, since I cannot estimate these parameters precisely enough.

So, do you have any experience values on when to combine images to a sprite and when *not*. (Actually, the "not" is more interesting IMHO).

Do you put all images on a sprite that "could" be needed for a single page, but anything that will only be needed by a second page on a separate sprite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, only group images together in a sprite if they are relevant.

If you have a menu based off of images, I'd make one image with all of the different elements in the menu. If you have a list with icons that appear on hover, make a spritesheet with all of those icons. It does you no good performance-wise to create one huge image when that same image can be combined into three or four smaller images.

It also helps to have only related images together - it keeps your CSS references to the files easier to follow and you have less complex x/y coordinate references.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I would do, but for likely navigation points you can pre-cache sprites by including an img tag with width and height set to 0 at the end of the body (after real content).  This will allow your page to load quickly and if you order the pre-cache img tags in order of most to least likely, it can still speed up navigation without slowing your home page down.

Answer (score 2):

here is my two cents... I usually try to sprite images for a given path that i am expecting to be hit harder then others. For example; if my sites so i call the critical path is: user logs on, goes to the home page, checks out today's deals, purchase one and logs out, i would like most of the common images sprited (logically grouped if needed) on this path. Having the sprites here will eliminate a lot of extra requests. 
If you go google.com you will see a sprite (nav_logo99.png) that has most of the common images you will need on the very likely next page(s).

Also to answer your "when not to sprite", background repeat and CSS sprites does not blend well so i will stay away from those.

Answer (score 1):

The thing I take into account is how many pages my user will visit. You have to remember that you sprite will normally be cached so only ever loaded once. 
If your site user runs around a few pages then its fine having a larger file but you are correct if most off your users only visit your home page then your not going to want to load all your sites images in one sprite.
Its best to just go on your own feel off what is best to optimize into sprites